# Track the scroll position beyond elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm putting together a jQuery plugin. The plugin takes panels, and auto-sizes their height. So I start off with something like this:

```
<div class="panel">Test 1</div>
<div class="panel">Test 2</div>
<div class="panel">Test 3</div>
```

The code for that looks something like:

```
    sizePanels: function(){
      panels.each(function(){
        $(this).height(docHeight);
      });
    },
```

There is a down button, that when clicked, will take the user to the next $(".panel):

```
nextPanel: function(){
  $.scrollTo($(".panel:eq(" + panelIndex + ")"), 250, { easing: "swing" });
}
```

With that, I'm keeping track of the panel index that their on:

```
    if (panelIndex < (panelCount - 1) ) {
      panelIndex += 1;
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to track if they happen to scroll manually, and pass one of the elements, to then increase the "panelIndex", so that the button doesn't move them up instead of down because it was never incremented properly due to the user using the scroll bar instead of the button. This is what I have so far:

```
   $(window).scroll(function(){
    panels.each(function(index){
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).scrollTop()) { 
        panelIndex = index; 
        // console.log(index);
      }
    });

    if (panelIndex < panelCount - 1){
      s.showDownButton();
    }
  });
```

The code excessively checks and feels somewhat overboard. is there a better way to do it?

Comment: In `$(window).scroll(function()` instead of **window** try to give id of panels' parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy optimization is to only calculate the scrollTop once and to exit the each loop when a match is found. You can exit a $.each loop by returning false.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    panels.each(function(index){
        if (scrollTop > $(this).scrollTop()) { 
            panelIndex = index; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (panelIndex < panelCount - 1){
        s.showDownButton();
    }
});
```

The next way that I would suggest optimizing this is to pre-calculate the scrollTop of each panel on page load (and when the viewport is resized). If you store these values in an array, then you can loop through them very quickly.

Here is some rough code to illustrate the idea:

```
var panelTops = [];

findPanelTops(); // calculate on load
$(window).on("resize", findPanelTops); // calculate on resize

function findPanelTops() {
    panelTops = [];
    panels.each(function(index) {
        panelTops.push($(this).scrollTop());
    });
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    for (var i = 0; i < panelTops.length; i++) {
        if (scrollTop > panelTops[i]) { 
            panelIndex = i;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    };

    if (panelIndex < panelCount - 1){
        s.showDownButton();
    }
});
```

The scroll event can fire a lot and very quickly, so you want to keep the amount of computation as minimal as possible. One way to get around all of this is to implement a scrollend handler. This will only fire when the scroll event has appeared to have stopped.

Here is some basic code for doing that. It will fire when the scroll event has stopped for more than 500ms:

```
var scrollTimeout = null;

function onScroll() {
    if (scrollTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    }
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(onScrollEnd, 500);
}

function onScrollEnd() {
    // Scrolling has stopped
    // Do stuff ...

   scrollTimeout = null;
}

$(window).on("scroll", onScroll);
```