# jquery scrolltop script not working

Tags: jquery, css, scrolltop

My ultimate goal is to get my header to switch from a position of relative to fixed when the window gets to a certain point. In trying to get there I came up with this function which doesn't give my any errors but also dosen't appear to do anything. Could someone help me understand why? It's the last script loaded on the page and jquery is called before it..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var $window = $(window);
function top() {
var $top = $window.scrollTop();
if( $top > 100 ) {
    $("header").css("position","absolute"); 
}
else {
    $("header").css("position","fixed");    
}
};
});
</script>
```

What if i wanted to limit it to mobil applications? shouldn't something like this work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
     var $window = $(window).width();
     function windowWidth() {
         if ( $window < 480 ) {
      function top() {
          var $top = $window.scrollTop();
          if( $top > 100 ) {
             $("header").css("position","absolute"); 
           }
           else {
              $("header").css("position","fixed");    
          }
     };
     $(window).scroll(top);
         }
     };
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(window).scroll(top)` or use `setTimeInterval(top, 100);`

Assuming header as id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
     var $window = $(window);
      function top() {
          var $top = $window.scrollTop();
          if( $top > 100 ) {
             $("#header").css("position","absolute"); 
           }
           else {
              $("#header").css("position","fixed");    
          }
     };
     $(window).scroll(top);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Window resize will only work if the window changes size. It doesn't track the position of the scroll bar.

Comment: @Styphon My intentation was scroll by mistake I wrote resize.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I took your code and put it in and it works great. Now i'm wondering how i would limit it when in happens to when it's viewed by mobil phones. I changed it up a bit but not getting much luck.

Comment: @StephenCrane header is a class or id? If it is class use $(".header") and if it is id use $('#header')

Comment: @Sushil Neither it's the html header tag.

Comment: @StephenCrane create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kVDag/. is this waht you want?

Comment: @Sushil Yes only i was hoping to limit it to a screen size of less then 400. something like http://jsfiddle.net/stephenrusselcrane/Qb8kc/

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not doing anything is you're not calling it. You have nothing to trigger the code. I assume it's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593891/track-the-scroll-position-beyond-elements#answer-10594396) script you found. If you notice it's wrapped in a $(window).scroll, instead of just function, to trigger it.

You need to modify your code thusly:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $("header").css("position","absolute"); 
    } else {
        $("header").css("position","fixed");    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not called the `.scroll()` function anywhere in the given code so it never going to be fired:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     var $window = $(window);
     function top() {
        var $top = $window.scrollTop();
        if( $top > 100 ) {
            $("header").css("position","absolute"); 
        }else {
            $("header").css("position","fixed");    
        }
     };
     $window.scroll(top);
  });
</script>
```